# Design considerations while developing web services for mobile applications

Tags: web-services, mobile-website

I have been developing server side applications in java, and now I have been asked to serve some mobile applications. The question always bugs me over "how much" data should I send to the app ?
If I have to transfer a large xml document, should I send it node by node, as per requirement....if yes, wont it consume the phone battery more (as the phone will be creating new connections for all the nodes). If I decide to send the whole document at once, it may take a long time for the client to download the whole doc, and may have problem temporarily storing it...even more, there may arise  data inconsistency in the two copies of data. In short, I need to know "is the creation of connection for a mobile device, too expensive ?" Which approach is better - receive data in chunks, by creating multiple connections OR receive all data together in one connection.

I also need to know, while developing my web service for the mobile clients, should I send them the image URI or the image data (as byte array) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download as few (times) as possible.
It´s the application that will answer your question. Don´t download lists of 1000 items, load just 10, wait the user scroll down, load next 10. cache the items.

A bit more tricky way to do soemthing like that is registering the user, that is downloading data, on the begining, he first time uses the app, it will download as many stuff as you need, call it the first time loading. Register, what the user downloaded. The next call from the user u send him only data that was changed, and send with this data the changeactions to perform on the clients device.

Answer (score 1):

With mobile clients, the latency kills more than the data package size. While you should not send more data than you are going to consume, node by node is not a good method to employ. This is not as much a battery answer as a user experience answer.

The best way to architect for mobile is find the right bite size for the meal. In other words, you don't send 10,000 records at one time, but you don't send a grid of 10 items 1 row at a time.

Depending on image size, you should send the image directly (base64 encoding is common) and not as a link. An exception would be sending the user to a web page and letting them browse, but then it is not really a "mobile application" any more, right?